# How can I refactor following code with prototypical inheritance?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I have a following code:

```
const myFunc = () => {
  let var1, var2, var3;

  const setVar1 = (val) => {
    var1 = val
  }

  return {
    setVar1
  }
}
```

Can you please tell me how this pattern is called(I read about it couple of days ago and can't remember)?

As far as I understand, at the moment I will produce each time new `object` with `setVar1` method in it and if I'll produce 1000 objects, I will get 1000 copies of `setVar1`(not sure, because I have only pointer to the function)?

Can/Should I refactor this code with prototypical inheritance? Can you please explain your reasoning behind your answer, it's very hard to understand this concept.

Thanks.

Comment: You're not inheriting anything, so the question is moot.

Comment: You're looking for [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)), correct?

Comment: @Alnitak I know it's probably sounds like a silly question to you, but can you please explain? I know it doesn't inheriting at the moment, that's why I asked two question regarding this principle.

Comment: @InSync Yes, I want to keep and operate on the `state` of the `myFunc` with private variables, that's why I created it this way.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think this is the revealing module pattern? It utilises a closure to implement private variables

Comment: @JohnMalkovich regardless of whether prototypical inheritance is used, there's two primary ways of implementing this - `var1` is either a property of an object that is accessible from any instance method using `this.var1`, or it's a locally scoped variable, exposed by a closure.  Until the recent introduction of private `#` prefixed object properties the latter was the only way to limit external access to the value.

Comment: @Alnitak Thank you for that explanation. So, correct me if I'm wrong, but it's basically a tradeoff between private scope with object copies and shareable methods without private scope. Right?

Comment: More or less, although #private properties now exist.  Personally for small methods forming closures over a small number if variables I wouldn't worry about the overhead of the multiple copies of the function.

Comment: Also note that it's not possible to clone any object that uses closures - the cloned closures will still refer to the original object's variables.

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks. And regarding the last comment, I don't really see scenarios(problematic) with this, but wouldn't that mean(if you want to clone that object) that you will simply need to run the `myFunc`? After all, if you clone the object, it will close *the* object, not the outer scope of it. And if you need that scope with cloned object, run `myFunc`.

Comment: I meant clone, not close

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do with prototypal inheritance. One of the main con is you can assign `__proto__` only one time.

```js
const object1 = {
  var: 'a',
  setVar: function(value) {
    this.var = value;
  },
  getVar: function() {
    return this.var;
  }
}

let object2 = {
  var: 'd'
}

object2.__proto__ = object1;

console.log(object2.getVar()); // Prints object2.var or 'd'
object2.setVar('e');           // Sets object2.var to 'e'
console.log(object2.getVar()); // Prints 'e'
```

I don't think you can access your `var1` or `setVar1` outside of the code of `myFunc` because it is scoped by the language and will create new instances of it every time you run this code.

What you might be looking for is an object-oriented class approach

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this._var1 = ''
    }

    get var1() {
        return this._var1
    }

    set var1(value) {
        this._var1 = value
    }
}
```

This does use prototypes, but behind the scenes. Dealing with prototypes explicitly is generally frowned upon, buf if you must:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.var1 = ''
}

MyClass.prototype.setVar1 = function(value) {
    this.var1 = value
}
```

When using closures, as in your post, all objects, including functions, are created from scratch, so yes, you'll end up with 1000 copies of the same function.

Comment: Thanks, I know about `classes` and in fact implemented the `class` version first, but I want to use `functions` instead and try to understand the "under the hood" mechanism of this, because as you can tell I don't really understand if `setVar1` gets copied 1000 times or it just gets the pointer etc

Comment: @JohnMalkovich: fair enough, updated

Comment: Thank you for the update, it does makes it clearer to understand

Answer (score 0):

It is true that you are creating a new `setVar()` every time you invoke `myFunc()`. Due to [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), `myFunc` creates a new variable, a setter function, and returns a new object everytime it is called. These look like the same, but under the hood they are not, as can be confirmed by `===`, which checks for identity when comparing objects (functions are also objects). We can verify this quite directly:

```js
console.log(myFunc().setVar1 === myFunc().setVar1); // false
```

Try it:

```js
/*<ignore>*/ console.config({ maximize: true }); /*</ignore>*/

const myFunc = () => {
  let var1;

  const setVar1 = (val) => {
    var1 = val;
  };

  return {
    setVar1
  };
}

const foo = myFunc();
const bar = myFunc();

console.log(foo.setVar1 === bar.setVar1); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

With `.prototype`, whenever you do a `instance.property` lookup, JS will first search its own keys set, then its prototypes. Since `foo` (and `bar`) has no own key named `setVar1` (the object constructed by `myFunc` has no `setVar1`, just `var1`), `myFunc.prototype.setVar1` will be returned instead:

```js
function myFunc() {
  this.var1 = undefined;
};

myFunc.prototype.setVar1 = function(val) {
  this.var1 = val;
};

console.log((new myFunc()).setVar1 === (new myFunc()).setVar1); // true
```

Try it:

```js
/*<ignore>*/ console.config({ maximize: true }); /*</ignore>*/

function myFunc() {
  this.var1 = undefined;
};

myFunc.prototype.setVar1 = function(val) {
  this.var1 = val;
};

const foo = new myFunc();
const bar = new myFunc();

console.log(foo.setVar1 === bar.setVar1); // true
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Since JS does have syntactic sugar for [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class) and [private properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields), you can and should just use that for ease of maintenance and readability:

```js
class myFunc {
  #var1;
  
  get var1() {
    return this.#var1;
  }
  
  set var1(val) {
    this.#var1 = val;
  }
}
```

Try it:

```js
/*<ignore>*/ console.config({ maximize: true }); /*</ignore>*/

class myFunc {
  #var1;
  
  constructor() {
    /* Do something... */
  }
  
  get var1() {
    console.log('getter');
    return this.#var1;
  }
  
  set var1(val) {
    console.log('setter');
    this.#var1 = val;
  }
}

const foo = new myFunc();

console.log(foo);        // Nothing from outside: {}
console.log(foo.var1);   // Logs 'getter', then returns undefined.

foo.var1 = 42;           // Logs 'setter'

console.log(foo.var1);   // Logs 'getter', then returns 42
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

You can also use [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to mimic the behaviour of private properties:

```js
function myFunc() {
  let var1;
  
  return new Proxy({}, {
    get(target, property) {
      if (property === 'var1') {
        return var1;
      } else {
         // Do something else...
      }
    },
    set(target, property, value) {
      if (property === 'var1') {
        var1 = value;
      } else {
         // Do something else...
      }
    }
  })
};
```

...or, to avoid recreating the handler object:

```js
const myFunc = (() => {
  const handler = {
    get() { /* ... */ },
    set() { /* ... */ }
  };
  return function myFunc() {
    // ...
    return new Proxy({}, handler);
  }
})();
```

Try it:

```js
/*<ignore>*/ console.config({ maximize: true }); /*</ignore>*/

function myFunc() {
  let var1;
  
  return new Proxy({}, {
    get(target, property) {
      if (property === 'var1') {
        console.log('getter');
        return var1;
      } else {
         // Do something else...
      }
    },
    set(target, property, value) {
      if (property === 'var1') {
        console.log('setter');
        var1 = value;
      } else {
         // Do something else...
      }
    }
  })
};

const foo = new myFunc();
const bar = new myFunc();

console.log(foo, bar);           // {}, {}
console.log(foo.var1);           // undefined

foo.var1 = 42;

console.log(foo.var1, bar.var1); // 42, undefined
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  for such detailed explanation, but if I want to use private properties with your "With .prototype" example and without `#`, how should I do that? I don't really see an option for that.

Comment: @JohnMalkovich Perhaps you can use `Proxy` for that. I updated the answer.

Comment: Wow, I never even heard about `Proxy`. Thank  you